# AWS codepipeline webhooks getting triggered if the branch name contains head_ref name

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, cicd, aws-codebuild

I have created a project in codebuild. I want to trigger this build only when there is a push on "main" branch. I added this on my webhook source event. THis is github webhook[image]

Problem I am facing is that the build is being triggered for every branch that contains "main" for example "dev/main" or "dev/user/main" etc.